# Unable to create hyper::Client because the compiler cannot infer enough type information

Tags: rust, type-inference, hyper

To experiment with Hyper, I started with [the GET example](http://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.9.4/hyper/client/index.html). Aside the fact that the example doesn't compile (`` no method `get` in `client` ``) I have distilled my problem to a single line:

```
fn temp() {
    let client = Client::new();
}
```

This code won't compile:

```
 unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
```

Comment: I tried this out for myself and couldn't reproduce the error. Do you have `extern crate hyper;` and `use hyper::Client;` in your file? Here's my working version: http://play.integer32.com/?gist=4debd4812508baf255f21715fbf44ef0

Comment: Pasted your code into my main.rs. Same error

Comment: Ok. When I use hyper from rust-lang repo this compiles, when I use hyper from hyper repo 
    hyper={git = "https://github.com/hyperium/hyper"}
This won't compile. That maybe explains why...

Answer (score 4):

In general this error would mean that `Client` has some generic parameter and the compiler can not infer it's value. You would have to tell it somehow.

Here is example with `std::vec::Vec`:

```
use std::vec::Vec;

fn problem() {
    let v = Vec::new(); // Problem, which Vec<???> do you want?
}

fn solution_1() {
    let mut v = Vec::<i32>::new(); // Tell the compiler directly
}

fn solution_2() {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = Vec::new(); // Tell the compiler by specifying the type
}

fn solution_3() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.push(1); // Tell the compiler by using it
}
```

**But** `hyper::client::Client` doesn't have any generic parameters. Are you sure the `Client` you are trying to instantiate is the one from Hyper?

Comment: Yes, I use the hyper::Client. I have a version of my code that uses Client and all is well, compiles and runs. But when I wanted to refactor this error came up.

Comment: So, there is a generic parameter:
https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/src/client/mod.rs

But I, probably as you did, looked in another documentation:
http://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.9.4/hyper/client/index.html

where there is no generic parameter